# Attempt local SSH Keys before Agent

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I have a key in a KeePass database made available using KeeAgent. I also have a key in the ~/.ssh folder.

When I attempt to SSH, it tries the key from KeePass first (even if I have an IdentityFile setup).

Is there anyway to have it try the agent after the local files?

I do not have a passphrase on the local key.